# Abstract - doublespace

Tags: line-spacing, abstract, thesis

I have got a problem with an abstract. I created a PHD Thesis in Latex. I use *thesis* document style. I want abstract to be doublespaced. I put that code to obtained it:

```
{\doublespacing
 \newpage\ifpdf\pdfbookmark[1]{Acknowledgement}{label:ack}\fi\input{acknowledge.tex}
 \newpage\ifpdf\pdfbookmark[1]{Abstract}{label:abst}\fi     \input{abstract.tex}
}
```

Unfortunately, everything is doublespaced, except the end of the abstract (see picture):
[image: The interline attribute is changed in the end of the abstract]

Does anybody has any suggestions? Regards.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I'm afraid that without more information about the contents of the file `abstract.tex` it's going to be impossible to diagnose with certainty what's going on. Real quick, though: What happens if you insert the instruction `\par` between `\input{abstract.tex}` and the closing `}` curly brace? Incidentally, do you use the `setspace` package, or is `\doublespacing` defined by you directly?

Comment: I use setspace package. Your clues helped me. I just put \par between \input{abstract.tex} and now everything is ok :). Thank you for help.

Comment: I think that with the `doublespace` environment (see my answer) it would work without you having to add `\par` to all your paragraphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to realize that the line spacing in effect for a *given paragraph* is determined by the settings that apply at the *end* of that paragraph, not by those at the paragraph's beginning.

Your code snippet doesn't indicate what comes immediately after the end of the group in which `\doublespacing` is in force. It also doesn't indicate what's at the end of the file `abstract.tex` -- specifically, whether there's either an implicit paragraph break (e.g., one or more all-blank lines) or an explicit paragraph break (e.g., `\par`). 
At any rate, it appears to be the case that there is currently no implicit or explicit paragraph break between the end of `abstract.tex` and the subsequent material; it would certainly explain why the final paragraph of the abstract is spaced differently from the preceding one.

There are several remedies, which all come down to providing that all-important paragraph break at the end of the abstract:

- Insert a `\par` statement between `\input{abstract.tex}` and the group's closing right curly brace, or immediately after that right curly brace.
- Insert one or more all-blank lines either immediately before or immediately after the right curly brace that terminates the scope of the `\doublespacing` command. (All-blank lines act like an implicit `\par` statement.)
- Use the `doublespacing` *environment* -- also provided by the `setspace` package -- instead of the `\doublespacing` command. Upon entering this environment, LaTeX will execute the command `\doublespacing` for you. When exiting from this environment, LaTeX will execute the command `\restore@spacing`; that command, in turn, executes -- you guessed it -- `\par`.

Answer (score 1):

Although I did not test it with the `thesis` package, I believe that the following could solve your problem.  Compare the following two documents:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
{\doublespacing                            % see here!
First paragraph, first line \newline
First paragraph, second line \newline
First paragraph, third line

Second paragraph, first line \newline
Second paragraph, second line \newline
Second paragraph, third line
}                                          % and here!
\end{document}
```

[image: wrong]

and

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\begin{doublespace}                        % see here!
First paragraph, first line \newline
First paragraph, second line \newline
First paragraph, third line

Second paragraph, first line \newline
Second paragraph, second line \newline
Second paragraph, third line
\end{doublespace}                          % and here!
\end{document}
```

[image: correct]

Therefore, I think you should fix your code to:

```
\begin{doublespace}
 \newpage\ifpdf\pdfbookmark[1]{Acknowledgement}{label:ack}\fi\input{acknowledge.tex}
 \newpage\ifpdf\pdfbookmark[1]{Abstract}{label:abst}\fi     \input{abstract.tex}
\end{doublespace}
```